# How to join output of two queries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Good morning.
I need help.

I have this code:

```
select A.AREA_CODE, A.OUTLET_NAME, SUM(B.AMOUNT) as NETSALES
from M_OUTLET A, T_SALES_DETAIL B 
where A.OUTLET_NO = B.OUTLET_NO and A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not
like '%head%' and A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%prod%' and 
A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%stor%'
and B.SYSTEM_DATE  between CONVERT (datetime, '3/1/2014') 
and CONVERT (datetime, '3/31/2014')
and B.VOID = 'N' group by A.AREA_CODE , A.OUTLET_NAME order by A.AREA_CODE
```

and this is the output:

```
AREA_CODE    OUTLET_NAME          NETSALES
1         MAKATI BU CAFE 2        226202.52
2         MAKATI BU CART          170305.01
```

The other code is this:

```
SELECT A.AREA_CODE, SUM (C.AMOUNT) AS E_SALES 
FROM E_SALES_DETAIL C , M_OUTLET A 
WHERE C.SYSTEM_DATE
between CONVERT (datetime, '3/1/2014') and 
CONVERT (datetime, '3/31/2014') and C.VOID = 'N'
GROUP BY A.AREA_CODE ORDER BY A.AREA_CODE
```

and the output is:

```
AREA_CODE     E_SALES
1            22208347.35
2            14453051.45
```

My question is, how can I join this codes to get this output:

```
AREA_CODE    OUTLET_NAME             E_SALES               NETSALES
    1         MAKATI BU CAFE 2      22208347.35             226202.52
    2         MAKATI BU CART        14453051.45             170305.01
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please change your title. 'I am new...' says nothing about your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your title. "I am new" is meaningless with regard to your question, and "Visual Studio 2010 and MS SQL Server 2008" are both things you can make available using tags. Your question should have information that tells us what the question is, and should be meaningful when a future user of this site finds it in a search result. While you're at it, you can remove "I need help" - that's clear because you posted here - and "thank you" - you can thank people by upvoting helpful answers and accepting one if it provides a solution.

Comment: how could you possibly write such complex queries and don't know what is actually doing?

Comment: If you really wrote those `where` clauses it should be a piece of cake for you to merge those two `select` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use your two queries as subqueries.  That said, I think you are missing a `join` condition on the second subquery:

```
select ab.area_code. ab.outlet_name, ab.netsales, ac.e_sales
from (select A.AREA_CODE, A.OUTLET_NAME, SUM(B.AMOUNT) as NETSALES
      from M_OUTLET A join
           T_SALES_DETAIL B 
           on A.OUTLET_NO = B.OUTLET_NO 
      where A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%head%' and
            A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%prod%' and 
            A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%stor%' and
            B.SYSTEM_DATE between CONVERT(datetime, '3/1/2014') and CONVERT(datetime, '3/31/2014') and
            B.VOID = 'N'
      group by A.AREA_CODE, A.OUTLET_NAME
     ) ab join
     (SELECT A.AREA_CODE, SUM(C.AMOUNT) AS E_SALES 
      FROM E_SALES_DETAIL C join
           M_OUTLET A 
           ON ????
      WHERE C.SYSTEM_DATE between CONVERT(datetime, '3/1/2014') and CONVERT(datetime, '3/31/2014')  and
            C.VOID = 'N'
      GROUP BY A.AREA_CODE 
     ) ac
     on ab.area_code ac.area_code;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir Gordon Linoff.